# Ada - Dynamically reallocate array

Tags: arrays, dynamic, memory-management, ada

I'm trying to write a stack based on array, that can be dynamically reallocated. The main problem I have is how to implement procedure that resizes the array. In C++ it could look like that:

```
template<class T, int incr>
void Vector<T, incr>::inflate(int increase) {
    const int tsz = sizeof(T*);
    T** st = new T*[quantity + increase];
    memset(st, 0, (quantity + increase) * tsz);
    memcpy(st, storage, quantity * tsz);
    quantity += increase;
    delete []storage;
    storage = st;
}
```

where `int quantity;` and `T** storage;` are declared in private section.

If there is anyone who could share me some sample I'd be much grateful. I tried to look through the implementation of Ada.Containers.Vectors but argh... it's to big =P

So far I've made this [Vector.ads](https://gist.github.com/496a50bc7f5cd93f8d91) Can anyone help?

Comment: When you say `Ada.Containers.Vectors` is too big, do you mean it uses too much memory or you're not sure how to make an instance behave as a stack?

Comment: I mean that the source code has 1772 lines and I cant fully grasp it =P Because I want to learn who to write such implementation, not just use it ;) Btw I will think about this solution (have some own ideas too) and when I finish it, or encounter a problem, I'll share it ;)

Comment: Excellent; more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8466813/230513).

Comment: your ads file looks good.. where's your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you know how to initially allocate the (empty) array for your stack.

When you need to reallocate to a larger array, allocate it into a local access variable, akin to "st" in your C++ example. Then loop though the existing, full array, copying its elements into your newly allocated one.

Free, using an instantiation of Unchecked Deallocation, the old array--that's the Elements field in your Vector record. Then set the Elements field to the variable containing the newly allocated array.

Essentially, it closely follows your C++ example, only you don't need to mess around with sizeof() and you use a copy loop instep of memset/memcpy.

Comment: Actually, @Marc, I think you’d copy a slice: `New_Elements (Index_Type’First .. V.Last) := V.Elements (Index_Type’First .. V.Last);`.

Comment: See also this implementation of [`Ada.Containers.Vectors`](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/gcc/ada/a-convec.adb), which uses `renames` and `:=`.

Comment: What with the standard containers, I wouldn't be writing my own stack implementation anyway, instead just build off one of them. One could implement a stack package using a Vector container, as per @trashgod, or just inherit directly from it and add Push() and Pop() convenience procedures, whereby direct access to the container's native procedures is also maintained.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, case is solved. I've finished my Vector class (which is actually a stack build on an array). Thank everyone for help.

Just for posterity here is my code. Hope someone will learn something from it. 
Code -> https://gist.github.com/496a50bc7f5cd93f8d91

If you'd like to take a look and find something worth changing just comment. ;D

Comment: I think you should make the Incr parameter to Inflate of type Positive; there seems to be a small memory leak if the first Inflate has Incr zero, and I hate to think what would happen if Incr was negative!

Comment: Sure, you are right. In fact I don't use the argument Inrc (and that's way I gave it a default value - probably that is the reason for such a blooper). Thanx, bug repaired ;) Thank God it was private, no user could kill my code except of me (probably the greatest danger) =P

Comment: +1 for following up and accepting @Mark's answer; now that you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation), consider up-voting it, too.

Comment: Nice code, Id like to see a Deflate method also to reduce memory footprint when possible also. After all if your program uses ~100 entries 99% of the time, and ~1000000 for 1% of the time, you will be memory inefficient as you will allocate 1000000, but never free them.

Comment: I haven't though about it but you may be right. Isn't it just that when you perform such inflate/deflate operations frequently you lead to memory fragmentation? Surely inflate is more dangerous, but using deflate can also help this unwanted process.

Comment: Repeated inflate/deflate operations would have that risk, however i would say a heuristic should be used to minimise the number of operations actually done. You are already doing this when you automatically allocate 100 spare elements. If you only deflate by 100 when there is 150 spares, then you should keep the number of deflates to a minimum. I have also seen schemes where the space doubles when it is 'full'.

Answer (score 5):

If you go with [`Ada.Containers.Vectors`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-18-2.html), there's a helpful discussion in the [*Rationale for Ada 2005: §8.2 Lists and vectors*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-8-2.html). Basically, you instantiate the generic package with your `Index_Type` and `Element_Type`:

```
package Container is new Containers.Vectors (Natural, T);
```

Then declare a variable having the new type:

```
Stack : Container.Vector;
```

The `Push` procedure then becomes `Stack.Append` and the `Pop` function returns `Stack.Last_Element`. Note the availability of [prefixed notation](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-2-3.html).